# Targeting clicked div with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, target

I have this block of code where when I hover (click for purposes of this example though but ultimately hover) on a particular box I want to target that div with universal jQuery code. I want the image inside the div to hide and a new div to appear and animate the width to say 250px. Been trying to target the second class of the div but to no avail. Anyone have any thoughts?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.partner_box').click(function() {
            var hidden_div;
            hidden_div = $(this).attr('class').eq(1);
            //hidden_div = $(hidden_div).eq(1).html();

            //hidden_div = hidden_div:nth-child(1);

            $(hidden_div + ' img').hide();
            console.log(hidden_div);

            //alert(hidden_div);
            //alert($(hidden_div).attr('class').split(' ')[1])

            /*$('.partner_box div').animate({
                top: '0px',
                right: '0px',
                bottom: '0px',
                left: '0px',
                display: 'block',
                position: 'absolute',
                width: '200px'
            });*/
        });
    });

    <div id="partner_grid">
        <!--LINE ONE-->
        <div class="partner_box partner_box1">
            <img src="images/partners/asx.jpg" alt="ASX" />
            <div style="display:none;">
                <p>This is the text for the slide.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_box partner_box2">
            <img src="images/partners/beauchamp.jpg" />
            <div style="display:none;">
                <p>This is the text for the slide.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_box partner_box3">
            <img src="images/partners/decillion_group.jpg" />
            <div style="display:none;">
                <p>This is the text for the slide.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="partner_box partner_box4">
            <img src="images/partners/dtcc.jpg" />
            <div style="display:none;">
                <p>This is the text for the slide.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to parse the classes effectively, so I just made unique ids for each slide.

```
$('.partner_box').click(function() {
    var hidden_div;
    hidden_div = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Thanks for all the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Trying changing:

```
$(hidden_div + ' img').hide();
```

to:

```
$('.' + hidden_div + ' img').hide();
```

Since you are targeting a class, you need to preface the class with a period.  That seems to be left out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not entirely sure of what you are trying to accomplish.  Here is an example of hiding the child image and showing the child div

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.partner_box').click(function() {

            var my_image = $(this).find("img");
            var hidden_div = $(this).find("div");

            my_image.hide();
            hidden_div.show();


        });
    });
```

The keyword "this" is tied to the element that triggered the event.  So while you are attaching a click event handler to all divs with a class of .partner-box only the one that is clicked while generate the event.

Answer (score 0):

Remember when you're inside an event like this that the `$(this)` refers to the particular element clicked. Not all elements with the selector you're using.

Take a look at this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ufomammut66/6y9XY/

If you click an element and check it out in console you'll notice I have it dumping out the `$(this)` element. In FireFox, if you have FireBug installed, mousing over the output will show the element `$(this)` refers to in that case. You should notice that the output element is particular to the clicked element.

From there you should be able to do whatever animations you need.